# SpriteKit zPosition Background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to make the background for the scene in `GameScene.sks`. I have `Tile Map Node` there, but when I set background in `GameScene.swift` the picture is on my textures. I want it on the back of the scene.

Here is the code of `GameScene.swift`:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BackGround")`
    override func didMove (to view: SKView) {
        background.zPosition = 1
        background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Here is the code of GameViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I know that I can make Background in GameScene.sks. But I want it in the code, so I can set up speed of background rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Does `1` the least z position in your scene? If so, try to set `ignoresSiblingOrder` property of your `SKView` to `false`. Also I would suggest you to read [SKScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene) and [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode) documentations at least. And [SpriteKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit) in general.

Comment: I have add some information. And I'm beginner at SpriteKit. Could you please explain me where and how I need to put it?

Comment: And I don't set all z positions. I make this because I thought it will help me)

Comment: The z position of the node in SpriteKit determines that nodes position in the render order of the SpriteKit rendering loop. If you are just setting your background node's `zPosition` it must be a negative value(i.e. -1) to place it "behind" other nodes.